# Plotly-Dash dbc.Button not downloading file properly on linux

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, streamlit

I'm using Dash for downloading the excel file which is already present with my code repo, when button is clicked(dbc.Button). Here is the code:

```
dbc.Button(        
            href=os.path.join("/", "static", "Template.xlsx"),
            download="Template.xlsx",
            external_link=True,
            children=["Download Template"],
                  style={
                "background-color": "#4CAF50",
                "border": "none",  # No border
                "fontWeight": "bold",
                "width":"200px",
                "marginBottom":"20px"
            }
        )
```

The code is working file in Windows i.e its downloading the file and file is opening properly but same code is not working in linux(deployed version), Its downloading the file(less file size: 6kb than usual: 14kb) and file is also showing corrupted

Answer (score 0):

This could be for a variety of reasons due to differences in the way your app is deployed on Linux vs. Windows. Which you don't specify. However, you might want to try first more robustly implementing the download functionality in the Python (Plotly Dash) code.

E.g., using `dash.dcc.Download` & `dash.dcc.send_file`:

```py
import os

import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, Dash

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Button(
            "Download Template",
            id="download-button",
            style={
                "background-color": "#4CAF50",
                "border": "none",
                "fontWeight": "bold",
                "width": "200px",
                "marginBottom": "20px",
            },
        ),
        dcc.Download(id="download"),
    ],
    style={"width": "50%", "textAlign": "center", "margin": "5%"},
)


@app.callback(
    Output("download", "data"), [Input("download-button", "n_clicks")]
)
def download_file(n):
    if n is None:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

    return dcc.send_file(
        os.path.join("/static", "Template.xlsx"), filename="Template.xlsx"
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If you're using nginx, etc., for production deployment on Linux, you'll have to make sure downloads from `/static` are configured to be allowed, of course.